# Storing ksh input array to variable and passing to another script

Tags: ksh, command-line-arguments

I have to modify an existing ksh script which looks at the command-line arguments using 'shift', and so empties $@, but now want to pass the original arguments to a second script afterwards.

In the mainline case I can do this by coping $@ to a variable and passing that to the second script, but I can't get it to work for quoted command-line arguments.

If I have a script called 'printer' like below:

```
#!/bin/ksh

INPUT=$@  
echo "Printing args"
until [[ $# -eq 0 ]];do
   echo $1
   shift
done

./printer2 $INPUT
```

and printer2 like below:

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "Printing second args"
until [[ $# -eq 0 ]];do
   echo $1
   shift
done
```

I would like the output of

```
./printer first second "third forth"
```

to be :

```
Printing args
first
second
third forth
Printing second args
first
second
third forth
```

I've tried various combinations of quotes around variables (both in the assignment of $INPUT  and when passing it to printer2) but can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

Ok I think I've found the solution after an awful lot of trial and error.

Assigning $INPUT like this:

```
set -A INPUT "$@"
```

and then passing it like this:

```
./printer2 "${INPUT[@]}"
```

produces the output I'm after.

The whole first script is therefore:

```
#!/bin/ksh

set -A INPUT "$@"  
echo "Printing args"
until [[ $# -eq 0 ]];do
   echo $1
   shift
done

./printer2 "${INPUT[@]}"
```

and

```
./printer first second "third fourth"
```

outputs:

```
Printing args
first
second
third fourth
Printing second args
first
second
third fourth
```

If anyone wants to explain the problem with the other things I tried, please do, as I'm still interested!

Comment: Relevant to my interests. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41357/what-is-the-most-correct-way-to-pass-an-array-to-a-function for the reasoning why.